# How to extend views in Metro / WinRT

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I am playing around trying to build the composite parts for doing MVVM with WinRT / Metro. I have built myself ViewBase which derive's from UserControl so I could use it to extend my views:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public abstract class ViewBase : UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewBase class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewBase() : base()
    {
        BindViewModelLocatorToView(viewModelLocator: GetViewModelLocator());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines a method that returns a view model locator to be used with this class.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract IViewModelLocator GetViewModelLocator();


    /// <summary>
    /// Defines a method that Bind's the view model provided by the view locator to the view's data context.
    /// </summary>
    private void BindViewModelLocatorToView(IViewModelLocator viewModelLocator)
    {
        if (viewModelLocator != null)
        {
            DataContext = viewModelLocator.ViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to extend the UserControl I am using as a view I get an error that this partial's parent must match the generated partial's parent. Of course I can't change the generated classes parent as it simply changes back on rebuild.

I notice in the sample apps included they are using the same concept with Layout aware page but I am not sure how they set the designer generated partial to match.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the root element in your XAML to `<ns:ViewBase>`, where `ns` is declared as the namespace your class is in.